# A hidden word riddle

Tags: riddle, word, word-property

Shown by surprise, you may be annoyed
Perused with intent, you may regret
Observed on this site, you may verify
Inclined on an airplane, you may have seen

Hint:

> Hint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the word all the lines are pointing at is

> SPOILER.

Shown by surprise, you may be annoyed

> ... although I believe research actually shows that people generally enjoy books, movies, etc., *more* after being "spoiled".

Perused with intent, you may regret

> Same meaning as the foregoing.

Observed on this site, you may verify

> As for instance in the hint above.

Inclined on an airplane, you may have seen

> [These](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoiler_(aeronautics)).

Comment: Well done! The main intent for this puzzle was actually to get a legitimate reason to use the contents of the hint as the hint :)